# HTML + CSS Modified Radiobutton only selecting first one

Tags: html, css

I can't make the second radiobutton ever be highlighted. As you can see from my attempts I tried to change name/value and combinations of. Tried in a form and outside of one. I am stumped on this simple piece of code. Can anyone direct me to fix my solution?

CSS:

```
.fb > input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + img{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + img{
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
```

HTML PART:

```
  <label class="fb" for="fb3">
    <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb" value="med" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>

<label class="fb" for="fb3">
    <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fab" value="mead" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>
```

JSBIN where I tried: http://jsbin.com/ziruloce/3/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ids **must** be unique. Try:

**[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/morexayi/1/edit)**

```
<form>
  <label class="fb" for="fb3">
    <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb" value="med" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>

<label class="fb" for="fb4">
    <input id="fb4" type="radio" name="fb" value="mead" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>
</form>
```

Note that I also made the names of your radio buttons the same.